# Haskell: Using multiple let and return a value after the do block inside a function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, let

As the title says, i want to return a value after the *do* block.

Example: Writing a function that inserts a variable at a given position in an array:

```
insertAt :: a -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
insertAt x n xs = do
            let before = take n xs
            let after  = drop n xs
            let merged = before ++ [x] ++ after
            in  merged
```

For example:

insertAt 'x' 3 "Aleander" => "Alexander"

Anyway, when using a single *let* call, one could return a value using the *in* keyword, but with the multiple calls of *let* as in the example i get the error:

*error: parse error on input `in'*

I know i could do the whole thing in a single *let* usage, but i want to know how to deal with multiple let calls :)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You don't need to use a `do` here at all.

Comment: Do *not* use `do` here. `do` expressions are syntactical sugar for expressions with bind functions.

Comment: without do i will get an error: parse error on input `let'

Comment: @MuradAlm.: please do not use *Voodoo programming* either https://www.techopedia.com/definition/22860/voodoo-programming :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's not a very helpful remark. Someone doing something wrong because they don't understand it can't just magically choose to understand instead. It takes a little study, practice, whatever. Calling it voodoo programming is just dismissive.

Comment: @amalloy: what I mean is that I see a lot of people that when having an error, just aim a series of substitutes until it eventually might typecheck, or produce sensical output. But unfortunately my experience is that (a) one can not per se guarantee that it works, it might have worked on a small subset, and (b) because it is trail and error, future ehancements, fixes, are again done through "voodoo programming", and thus yielding (a) again.

Comment: @amalloy: I did not come up with the name voodoo programming, it is more the idea of adding some things, removing some things, and hope that "magic" will "click", is usually not very effective. I agree that "voodoo programming" is a bit (over)offensive.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it wasn't just adding and removing stuff and hoping it will work.
I've started to learn Haskell (my very first functional programming language) a couple days ago (and i'm already in love) and that's why i'm still confused and trying to get out of the OOP principles

Comment: I appreciate your help, and thanks for the advice.

Comment: @MuradAlm: It was not meant to be that offensive, sorry if that was the effect. Probably I interpreted "*without `do` i will get an error: parse error on input `let`*" a bit the wrong way (as in "I got an error without, so I added `do`). The question shows that you have put effort into it, and although it was no completely successful, it was quite close to the correct result. So I did +1. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please do *not* use a `do` expression. `do` expressions are snytactical sugar for expressions with binds. Yes a list is an instance of `Monad`, but you use it not in the correct way.

You can here define your `let`s in a block like:

```
insertAt :: a -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
insertAt x n xs =
    let before = take n xs
        after = drop n xs
        merged = before ++ [x] ++ after
    in  merged
```

But it might be more elegant to use [**`splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt), like:

```
insertAt :: a -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
insertAt x n xs = let (hs,ts) = splitAt n xs in hs ++ x : ts
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the list monad, though, you can write

```
insertAt x n ys = do
   (i, y) <- zip [0..] ys
   if i == n then [x, y] else [y]
```

This works by "numbering" each element of the input list. Normally, you just return each element as you find it (remember, `return x == [x]` in the list monad). But at position `n`, you want to "sneak in" `x` before the current element of the existing list. You do that by providing the list `[x,y]` instead of simply `[y]`.

`insertAt 'x' 3 "Aleander"` essentially becomes `concat ["A", "l", "e", "xa", "n", "d", "e", "r"]`.

---

Drawback: it won't append `'x'` to the output, regardless of what `n` you supply, so this may be more of a demonstration of the list monad than a solution to your actual problem. One simple fix is to special case `n == 0`, then insert `x` *after* the `n` the element. This lets you append if `n == length ys`, but not `n > length ys`:

```
insertAt x n ys = if n == 0 then x:ys else do
    (i, y) <- zip [1..] ys  -- Note the increase in indices
    if i == n then [y, x] else [y]
```

Comment: Wow! i didn't think about it in that way!
thanks a lot!
i love the fact that i'm able to do things in 3 lines of code in Haskell, that would take 30 in Java (for example)!